# getting a 'The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasInputDevices.' error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

im a newbie in c# and selenium.

Im trying to create an element extension to mouseover an element.
I've got the following:

```
public static void mouseoverElement(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
{           
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);      
    actions.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

}
```

And this would be called from another class

```
public MLinks mouseOverCandidate()
{
candidateMenu.mouseoverElement(driver);
return this;
}
```

And this is where i will call from the test:

```
new HomePage(driver, server)
    .MainLinks.mouseOverCandidate();
```

I will always get this which i don't quite understand. I've already got a driver set. Anyone can help me out on this? thanks

```
System.ArgumentException : The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasInputDevices.
```

Comment: What type of `IWebDriver` is it?

Comment: im using IE webdriver

Answer (score 2):

The method *mouseoverElement* is taking an IWebDriver, which is an interface.

The concrete driver class implements this interface, as well as the other interface *IHasInputDevices*.

So you need to pass in the concrete class, so that it can expose *IHasInputDevices*, as well as *IWebDriver*

Comment: can you please tell more about this? I have the same problem. The drive I'm passing to Actions class is a ChromeDriver. But I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you will also get this error if the WebDriver you pass in is null.